# PHP clone static $var, to keep it unique in every instance?

Tags: php, static, clone

I have a class, that is instantiated multiple times in a extended class. I want a static var, to be unique for every instance to keep the child instance of where the object that contains the variable is instantiated from.

**Example:**

```
abstract class parent
{
    protected $inst;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->inst = new inst($this);
    }
}

class inst
{
    private static $_child; // I want this variable to be unique so that in $child1->inst it would be the instance of the first child and in $child2->inst it would be the instance of the second child

    public function __construct($child_inst) 
    {
        self::$_child = $child_inst;
    }
}

class child1 extends parent 
{

}

class child2 extends parent 
{

}
```

I hope that it's explained clear enough.

**Edit:**
By the way, if I remove static I'm creating a loop, and the variable is set in both instances, so that's not an option. I want the variable to be different for each instance.

Comment: Don't make it static and the problem is solved.

Comment: If i don't make it static, i'm gonna have a recursion (loop), and the var is set in both instances of inst-class?

Comment: it's either static or unique. pick one.

Comment: The very nature of static variables is that they are same for all instances - to be more precise, static variables do not event depend on object instances, they just "are".

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up changing it. :)